Open game mode in android java
i want to open system game mode or game space in my android java
My Vivo phone has a "Game Space" application, it works automatically on games I download from Google Play, but I can't run it in my own game app. Also, other Android phones have a Game Mode app, how can these phones know that my application is a game?. When my android java application open in device then automatically open system game mode or game space or game booster, i want to set my app like this.
tried :


android:isGame="true"



<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    ...>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.game_mode"
        android:value="true" />

    ...
</application>



It's android:appCategory="game" and you'd need to add a game_mode_config.xml.

give me solution
